# Regex working in tester, but not in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

In the string

```
 <td class="useragent"><a href="/useragents/parse/627832-chrome-windows-blink">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36</a></td>
```

I am trying to extract and copy to clipboard

> Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

Using the regex tester at https://regexr.com/, I found that this regex accomplishes what I am seeking:

```
(?<=<td class="useragent"><a href=".*">).*(?=</a>)
```

When I try it in Sublime Text, it doesn't.  I'm guessing this has to do with different 'flavors' of RegEx, so how can I change this RegEx to work with Sublime Text?

Comment: Try this one: `<td\s+class="useragent".*><a\s+.*>(.*)</a></td>`

Comment: What's this `(?<=.*)` ? Show a perma=link to where you tested this specific regex.

Comment: @AntonioDias I receive the message 'Unable to find <td\s+.*><a\s+.*>(.*)</a></td> in selection' when searching through an HTML file full of similar strings to what I posted

Comment: Maybe it is something related with multiline matching. Unfortunately I don't have Sublime here and my guess was purely based on regex.

Comment: @AntonioDias Thanks anyways, luckily someone else was able to help me figure it out.  I appreciate the fast response even if it didn't work in my case.

Comment: You need to give more information about where the `useragent` will be. It's not enough. You're just squeezing arbitrary text inbetween fixed literal tags. Won't work. If it is all literal text, then you don't need all the tag stuff at all, just a few literal anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sublime Text 3 Regex Solution

You cannot use a lookbehind of unknown length in PCRE regex (it is the regex library that is used in Sublime Text 3). However, since you are using a positive lookbehind, you may use **`\K` match reset operator** instead (it will discard all text matched so far from the match memory buffer).

Also, you might consider some enhancements:

- `".*"` might overflow across tags, use `"[^"]*"` instead
- `.*</a>` may get to the last `</a>` on a line, use `.*?</a>` to get to the first one
- If there are line breaks in the `<a>` node, use `(?s)` DOTALL inline modifier to make `.*?` match across lines

Use

```
(?s)<td class="useragent"><a href="[^"]*">\K.*?(?=</a>)
                                          ^^
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/50wLmH/1).

ST3 test:

[image]

See [Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) at *regular-expressions.info*.

## PHP Fallback Using DOM Parsing

You should actually be cautious with parsing out data from arbitrary HTML. If you want to get all the texts you need from a big HTML, you should consider using a full-fledged HTML DOM supporting technology. Here is an example using PHP ([**see an online PHP demo**](https://3v4l.org/IgutI)):

```
$text = <<<EOD
<td class="useragent"><a href="/useragents/parse/627832-chrome-windows-blink">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36</a></td>
EOD;
$domDocument = new DOMDocument;
$domDocument->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//td[@class="useragent"]/a');
$res = [];
foreach($nodes as $txt) { 
   array_push($res, $txt->textContent);
}
print_r($res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
)
```

Here, `$text` is your HTML text, `//td[@class="useragent"]/a` is an XPath that gets all `td` nodes whose `class` attribute value is equal to `useragent` and then grabs `a` node inside them. The actual text is returned with `$txt->textContent`.

Comment: I receive the message 'Unable to find <td class="useragent"><a href=".*">\K.*(?=</a>) in selection' at the bottom of the Sublime Text windows while searching through a HTML file full of the same patterns I posted.

Comment: Are there line breaks inside `<a ...>... </a>`?

Comment: Stribizew Nope, I edited my question to remove them, not sure how they ended up in my example.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/50wLmH/1, this is what you should get in ST3. I also added an ST3 screenshot with your sample data.

Comment: Ok, your edited answer seems to be working.  I will mark it as the answer  when I have the option to do so.

Comment: All those spaces should be replaced with `\s+`, a `\s*` should be added </a`here`> and, attributes can be anywhere within a tag, and more than 1. So, basically this won't work...

Comment: @DavidStampher I also added an example of using DOM to parse out the necessary details from HTML using PHP. No idea if it helps, but this is way safer than using regex.

Answer (score 0):

All I have around here is Python and I tested `<td class="useragent"><a .*>(.*)</a></td>` against the string you posted and it works. Look

```
>>> import re
>>> agent=re.compile(r'<td class="useragent"><a .*>(.*)</a></td>')
>>> s='<td class="useragent"><a href="/useragents/parse/627832-chrome-windows-blink">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36</a></td>'
>>> agent.findall(s)
['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36']
>>>
```

I hope that helps.